# how to get products names from amazon

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I saw all the relevant previous topics about that manner and i've learned a lot (especially about the difference between lxml and html.parser)
    anyway after i changed my BeautifulSoup to parse the page as lxml I still can't get all the time the same result .
    most of the time i get : "  name = soup.find('span', id="productTitle").text
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'  "
    but in a few times i get the real name of the product.
    what am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/Homego-Bluetooth-Wrist-Smart-Handsfree/dp/B01DOULDN0/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=smart+watch&qid=1569450390&sr=8-1"
    client = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Defined"})
    try:
        client.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print("Error!!!!" + str(e))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(client.content, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find('span', id="productTitle").text
    title = name[161:len(name)-128]
    print("the title is: ", title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are getting different html back. Check the html itself. You can add in a test of whether variables are None before attempting to access .text

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/Homego-Bluetooth-Wrist-Smart-Handsfree/dp/B01DOULDN0/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=smart+watch&qid=1569450390&sr=8-1"
    client = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Defined"})
    try:
        client.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print("Error!!!!" + str(e))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(client.content, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find('span', id="productTitle")
    if name is None:
        name = 'N/A'
        title = 'n/a'
    else:
        name = name.text    
        title = name[161:len(name)-128]
    print("the title is: ", title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: actually what i meant is that for the same page itself i get error sometimes and sometimes i get the actual product name.

Comment: You already have error handling around the request status. The above at least prevents the error of different html coming back e.g. redirect page, captcha page, some other variant.